# Neatly Transforming Anorm ResultSet Into Map[Parent , (Set[Child1], Set[Child2]))]

Tags: sql, functional-programming, scala

I have a table `Bill` containing `Bills` with 0...n relationships to `Material` and `Activity` (line items on the bill).

My SQL query is essentially bill left join material left join activity.

I have the following insanely tangled code to transform the results into a `Map[Bill, (HashSet[Activity], HashSet[Material])]`.

What's wrong with this code?  Is this whole approach wrong?  I'm new to Scala and the functional world, but it doesn't seem like this could be the right way.

```
 SQL(
          """
            |SELECT
            | b.id, b.dateDue
            | ,a.id as activityId, a.notes, a.startTime, a.endTime
            | ,m.id as materialId, m.cost, m.description, m.storageLocation
            |FROM Bill b
            |LEFT JOIN Activity a ON a.bill_id = b.id
            |LEFT JOIN Material m ON m.bill_id = b.id
            |WHERE b.id = {id}
          """.stripMargin)
        .on("id" -> id)
        .as(betterParser *)
        .groupBy( x=> (x._1, x._2))
        .map( q => q._1 -> 
                q._2.foldLeft( (HashSet[Activity](), HashSet[Material]()) ) 
                ( (acc, item) =>  (acc._1 + item._3, acc._2 + item._4)))
```

betterParser transforms each row from the query into a (Long, DateTime, Activity, Material) where the  (Long, DateTime) portion are overall bill poperties.

```
 val betterParser = {
    billParser ~ activityParser ~ materialParser map {
      case bill ~ activity ~ material =>
       (bill._1, bill._2, activity, material)
   }
 }
```

Comment: I don't know Scala, I think your SQL looks fine. I would really like to see someone with Scala knowledge answer this.

Comment: @Phrancis  I haven't heard from anyone.  I'm currently working on my own solution, which is a bit outside of the scope of the original question.  I'm implementing a ResultSetParser that allows you to specify one hub parser and 0...n spoke parsers.   Results are grouped by hub items.  Each spoke parser populates a HashSet attached to the hub.   (So you can do SQL(...).as( hub[Bill](billParser) seive[Activity](activityParser) seive[Material]("materialParser)  and get the equivalent of a Seq[(Bill, Set[Activity],Set[Activity])].

Comment: I think you should post your own solution as an answer, once it is ready, I'm sure it would benefit someone in the future!

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't issue 3 separate SQL queries, one for each table, all using the `Bill` primary key. There is absolutely no benefit having the database do the joins, nor in having Anorm tear everything apart.

Comment: @bob dalgleish I simplified my example. An actual praftice, the join foreign keys are not all the bill pk, meaning that multiple queries would have to be sequenced.  Also what about the overhead and network latency involved in a query?  Wouldn't that make the 3 query approach slower?

Comment: @bob dalgleish also, with the one query approach SQL optimizer is more likely to be able to execute query in most performant way possible.  Obviously in this simplified example there's not too much to optimize.  In general though, the folks at ms, oracle and so on have put a lot of work into making performant db engines.  Why not build on that work rather than rebuilding the wheel at the application level?

Comment: You are assuming that a single query on three tables doesn't have synchronization issues. How about turning it upside down and creating 3 DB connections on 3 threads and let the DBMS handle the parallelism. Also, I don't get your "3 table access" is more efficient than "1 table access" argument.

Comment: @Bob Dalgleish because I don't have the foreign keys to query some of the secondary tables until at least one query returns, so they'd have to be sequenced application side.

Comment: @Bob Dalgleish re: optimization, with a single query db engine can put together a better execution plan, for example if some of the where conditions exclude some rows from the secondary or tertiary tables

Comment: Re: parallelism.  Even if the queries could be executed in parallel, wouldn't I be increasing network load and query processing overhead N times?  (Db engine has to deal with n tranascations instead of 1, n connections from my connection pool are being used instead of 1 and so on.), I might be missing something though.

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping someone would review your [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) but I don't think it's going to happen. So I thought I would at least say something about [sql](/questions/tagged/sql).

**Alias names**

Table aliases are handy especially for very long table names, however I feel that your naming is too minimal. Single-letter aliases tell Mr. Maintainer nothing about what the table means, and it can get confusing if you have multiple tables starting with the same letter. `b`, `a`, `m` are not very useful. Instead I would use `Bill`, `Act`, `Mat` or something similar.

**Formatting**

Your formatting is not bad, I see you've kept columns from the same table on the same line and that's good; but inline SQL can be a bit difficult to read especially when you introduce column aliases. My recommendation is to use a line break after each column you `SELECT`. I also noticed a bit of inconsistency in capitalization of key words.

This:

```
 SQL(
          """
            |SELECT
            | b.id, b.dateDue
            | ,a.id as activityId, a.notes, a.startTime, a.endTime
            | ,m.id as materialId, m.cost, m.description, m.storageLocation
            |FROM Bill b
            |LEFT JOIN Activity a ON a.bill_id = b.id
            |LEFT JOIN Material m ON m.bill_id = b.id
            |WHERE b.id = {id}
          """.stripMargin)
```

I would instead write like this:

```
 SQL(
          """
            |SELECT Bill.id
            | ,Bill.dateDue
            | ,Act.id AS activityId
            | ,Act.notes
            | ,Act.startTime
            | ,Act.endTime
            | ,Mat.id AS materialId
            | ,Mat.cost
            | ,Mat.description
            | ,Mat.storageLocation
            |FROM Bill
            |LEFT JOIN Activity AS Act ON Act.bill_id = Bill.id
            |LEFT JOIN Material AS Mat ON Mat.bill_id = Bill.id
            |WHERE Bill.id = {id}
          """.stripMargin)
```